# Flame Sensors Problems

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, hardware

I am making a fire fighting robot and I need a sensor. I want the sensor detection range to be about 6m or 7m (about 18ft to 20ft).

The question is which sensor should I choose to get that detection range? I've found that some small IR sensors are not suitable for my range required.

I'm making a simulated one. It might be confused if there are non-fire distractions so I'm asking for a technique that can improve the sensor range and determination very very effective... or which sensor should I choose??

I don't want the IR sensor to be more directional. If I need it to be more directional I can use 2 or 3 or more. It is no problem. I want the IR sensors to improve their detection range. I can only get 2m now. I want it to be about 4m or 5m.

Comment: Are you fighting real fires or simulated ones such as a candle in a maze?  What possible non-fire distractions exist in the environment which might confuse it?

Comment: You'd probably want the IR sensor to be more directional. Try putting some heat-shrink around the sensor, so it can only see light from straight ahead.